# Creating a Transposed Matrix in C

Tags: c, identity

## Creating a Program to print a Transposed Matrix

I'm creating a program in C where the user must define the number of rows and columns of a matrix, then the program must create random numbers  and print the Transposed Matrix. I've achieved the first part, but my code isn't working for creating the Transposed Matrix. If it's a squared matrix, it must calculate also the D(mxn) * I(mxn), where D is the matrix and I the Identity matrix.  Here`s the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    unsigned short i, j, m, n;
    int matriz[m][n], mTransposta[m][n], random;
    

    printf("Entre a dimensao m da matriz: ");
    scanf("%hu", &m);

    printf("Entre a dimensao n da matriz: ");
    scanf("%hu", &n);

    printf("A matriz randomizada e:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < m;i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < n;j++) {
            random= rand()%100;
            matriz[m][n]= random;

            printf("%i ", matriz[m][n]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("A matriz Transposta e:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            
            mTransposta[m][n]= matriz[n][m];
        }

        printf("%i ", matriz[m][n]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What is `m` and `n` in `matriz[m][n]`?? Meaning what values do they have at the time  `matriz[m][n]` is reached? Same issue with `mTransposta[m][n]`

Comment: R. A. A., Question is at best implied.  Best to ask a clear question.

Comment: Where you have `int matriz[m][n], mTransposta[m][n]` in the code, the values of `m` and `n` are _undefined_. That is, `m` and `n` have not yet been assigned values. Move the line to _after_ all the `scanf` calls that define `m` and `n`.

Answer (score 1):

At least these problems

**Declared too early**

When `int matriz[m][n]` is declared, `m, n` do not have assigned values.  Declare `int matriz[m][n]` *after* assigning `m, n`.

```
// int matriz[m][n], mTransposta[m][n], random;

printf("Entre a dimensao m da matriz: ");
scanf("%hu", &m);

printf("Entre a dimensao n da matriz: ");
scanf("%hu", &n);

int matriz[m][n], mTransposta[m][n], random;
```

**Transposed array**

This implies `mTransposta[m][n]` should be `mTransposta[n][m]`

**Print more often**

`printf("%i ", matriz[m][n]);` only prints in an outer loop.  Expect that in an inner loop.

**Unused `mTransposta[m][n]`**

Code never reads the values in `mTransposta[m][n]=`.

**Other**

- `scanf()` return values not checked.
- `D(mxn) * I(mxn)` code missing.
- Identity matrix never formed.
- Printing a space after the last number is poor form.  Alternative:

```
        const char *sep = "";
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < n;j++) {
            matriz[m][n] = rand()%100;
            printf("%s%i", sep, matriz[m][n]);
            sep = " ";
        }
        printf("\n");
```